# Why is my overloaded template function is promoting to const differently then a non-template function.

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

I have a overloaded function that works correctly. (f in the example). When I convert it to a template version of the same thing, it breaks by always calling the T& version, never the T*. (t in the example) When I make a non-const version of the template function it works as expected. (t2 in the example) This occurs in both VS2010 and g++ 4.6.2. Are the promotion to const rules different, or is this a bug of some sort.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int f(const int&x){return 1;}
int f(const int*x){return 2;}

template <class T> int t(const T &x){return 3;}
template <class T> int t(const T *x){return 4;}

template <class T> int t2(T &x){return 5;}
template <class T> int t2(T *x){return 6;}

int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    int x=0;
    cout<<f(x)<<endl;
    cout<<f(&x)<<endl;
    cout<<t(x)<<endl;
    cout<<t(&x)<<endl;
    cout<<t2(x)<<endl;
    cout<<t2(&x)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

the output is

```
1
2
3
3
5
6
```

Comment: More clarification: t((const int *)&x) works as expected.

Comment: +1 for a short, complete test case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `int x` isn't `const`. So `&x` yields an `int*`. Here are the two candidate functions:

- `int t<int*>(T const&)` (equivalently `int t<int*>(int * const&)`) <-- T is `int*`; requires 0 conversions
- `int t<int>(T const*)`  (equivalently `int t<int>(int const*)`)  <-- T is `int`; requires a conversion from `int*` to `int const*`

The better match, i.e. the one without a conversion, is chosen. That's the reference version.

Answer (score 2):

In these two cases:

```
cout<<t(x)<<endl;
cout<<t(&x)<<endl;
```

the `template <class T> int t(const T &x)` overload is being selected by the compiler, because `T` can be satisfied by `int` and `int *`, respectively.

In this case:

```
cout<<t2(&x)<<endl;
```

the `template <class T> int t2(T &x)` overload is not selected, because it cannot be satisfied.  You cannot bind a reference to a temporary (rvalue), and `&x` is a temporary.

Comment: There has to be a reason other then references to rvalues. Because if I create a pointer variable to hold the rvalue it still calls the same function. int *p=&x; t2(p); ->6